# Sonarqube - How to exchange data with Compute Engine MeasureComputer implementation from Sensor

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I am working on implementing SonarQube plugin for a custom platform specific language. The documentation is very limited and any code examples I see are outdated - usage of Decorators instead of MeasureComputer etc. I went through the sample plugin but it does not have the context I am looking for. My question is - how do I exchange the data between the Sensor and MeasureComputer implementation. The plugin invokes a command-line (vendor specific and I cannot change) that writes the data to a file. I would like the data from this file displayed in the General Metrics screen. In Sensor execute method, I am able to parse the file but I cannot save the Measure as the API has changed now and requires me to save the Measure with .on method that requires an InputFile, but this data is on the entire project and not on a file. I am not able to do a simple save of Metric on the project. I tried using MeasureComputer implementation, but I understand that this runs in Background task on server side, so I thought of setting the property under context.settings.setString("propName", "value") and tried retriving it using (MeasureComputerContext) context.getSettings().getString("propName"). This is not working either.

1. Can I save a Metric on the context that can be displayed in General inside a Sensor on the project and not the resource in 5.6.6 version. If so how?
2. If above is not possible, how can I store the file content to exchange with MeasureComputer, either add to list of files or set the property or object to be retrieved in MeasureComputer.

Thanks in Advance for your help. I have spent considerable time on this and the documentation leaves a lot to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else ending up here, looking for an answer, see the answer posted by Julien Henry on Google Groups here - https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sonarqube/yWsp7vuIsSo/ZugXMkp8CwAJ. Essentially, you can set the property at module level using .on(context.module()) and use it in Compute Engine.